# RobotFramework: Why write tests in keywords/robot-framework syntax at all?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm not asking why we should use RobotFramework at all, I'm only asking why we should write tests using their syntax and not write tests entirely as custom libraries.

Say we want to write a test that looks at a directory and ensures that no files in that directory have been changed. You can write it in RobotFramework with their `Get Files In Directory` and `Get Modified Time` keywords and its syntax for writing loops, or you could just write your own test that does that entirely in Python (loops through files in a directory and ensures that each file's modified time is before when you run any code you're testing).

As a Python developer (and not RobotFramework developer), I want to default to writing everything in Python and use the RobotFramework syntax only to check if those custom tests are True, False, etc. (Just out of comfort.)

Edit: To clarify, the test to check modified files would be an individual check inside a test case, not an entire test itself.

Comment: Well, in my opinion it's usually a bad idea to reinvent the wheel. You'll end up with a worst version of what already exists. Also, custom code means specific internal maintenance, which has its cost. It's better to use a common third party library, new developers on you project will probably know them and will be ready to work immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, robot framework is for testing behaviors, not functions.

For the scenario you proposed, there is no reason to write that test in Robot Framework. However, it seems likely that this one check you're doing is actually part of some bigger feature.

For example, maybe you have code that creates a presentation based on files in a folder, and you want to make sure that once the presentation has been built, none of the files in the folder were modified. Or maybe you've written a program that will clean out a folder, but you can specify sub-folders that shouldn't be included. You, therefore, need to write a test that verifies that after running the program the files in the excluded folder haven't been touched.

Those are features or behaviors of a program described at a high level: "can build a presentation without modifying the original files" or "can exclude a directory from processing". For those, you need to write acceptance tests, and Robot Framework is a good choice for writing those acceptance tests.

For example, let's say the program is performing some processing and needs to exclude a folder. You would want to write a Robot test like this:

```
*** Test cases ***
Verify exclude feature works
    Verify the folder exists  ${data dir}/important
    Process the files  ${data dir}   exclude=important
    Assert the excluded folder didn't change  ${data dir}/important
```

You would then put the logic for checking all of the files inside the keyword `Assert the excluded folder didn't change`, and call that keyword after doing some processing. With that, you can prove that the high level features of your program are working as the customer expects.

In other words, Robot framework isn't a tool to help an individual programmer test an individual function. Instead, it's a tool to help a team verify the behavior of an application as a whole.